# Create new column in Pandas DataFrame based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe like:

[image]

Now I would like to add column V based on conditions on I1, I2 and I3. Conditions are like:

```
v = 1 if I1>23 and I2.str.contains('abc')
v = 2 if I3 == 20
v == ...............
...................
```

One row can satisfy multiple condition what I want is to multiply such rows and filter out the rows which is not satisfying any condition such as suppose N1 will satisfy for V=1,2 and 3. While N2 does not satisfy any and N3 will satisfy v=2.
I want the final dataframe to look like:

[image]

Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, suppose you have a dataframe like the below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "NAME": [ "N1", "N2", "N3" ],
    "I1": [ 1, 4, 4 ],
    "I2": [ 2, 5, 2 ],
    "I3": [ 3, 6, 6 ]
})
```

i.e:

```py
>>> df
  NAME  I1  I2  I3
0   N1   1   2   3
1   N2   4   5   6
2   N3   4   2   6
```

To reproduce your example, I will assume that the conditions are `I1 = 1`, `I2 = 2`, and `I3 = 3`:

```py
cond1 = df["I1"] == 1
cond2 = df["I2"] == 2
cond3 = df["I3"] == 3
```

To build the expected dataframe, you can do:

```py
result = pd.concat([
    df[cond1].assign(V=1),
    df[cond2].assign(V=2),
    df[cond3].assign(V=3)
])
```

Result:

```py
>>> result
  NAME  I1  I2  I3  V
0   N1   1   2   3  1
0   N1   1   2   3  2
2   N3   4   2   6  2
0   N1   1   2   3  3
```